# Mongodb on Terminal keeps getting stuck

Tags: macos, mongodb, terminal

I have a Macbook Pro with El Capitan. I installed mongodb on my terminal with macports, which is similar to homebrew. I've followed all of the instructions and I've made sure to change the user permissions to /data/db. Does anyone have any idea of what's wrong with my mongodb installation?

Whenever I try to run "mongod", it keeps pausing at "waiting for connections on port 27017". This is shown in Screenshot 1. Then I hit CTRL-C to exit, and I get more error messages shown in Screenshot 2. Also the "mongo" command does not work either.

Here is the error report shown when entering "mongo".

`MongoDB shell version: 3.0.8
connecting to: test
2016-01-11T19:08:41.888-0600 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:61 Connection refused
2016-01-11T19:08:41.890-0600 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
    at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179:14)
    at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179
exception: connect failed`

Here is a link to my google drive with a photos of the error report for "mongod".

Screenshot 1 - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwl_BDx-HIfcYnBJRUJfbzFvSm8/view?usp=sharing
Screenshot 2 - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwl_BDx-HIfcdkVkUWJzeENuelU/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Whenever I try to run "mongod", it keeps pausing at "waiting for connections on port 27017".

This is exactly what it is supposed to do. Unless you indicate otherwise via a command switch (such as "--fork"), running "mongod" starts up the mongo server process within the current shell and blocks that shell until the process is terminated (via CTRL+C).

If you want to connect to the running mongo server process via the mongo shell, you'll need to open a second terminal to do so. From there, run "mongo" and it should connect to the server running in the first terminal shell.

Re-cap:

In terminal #1, run "mongod". When it says "waiting for connections...", it's ready to accept client connections. Do not stop the process via CTRL+C; do not close that terminal.

In terminal #2, run "mongo". It should connect to the server successfully.

Answer (score 1):

This "connection refused" message is significant:

```
2016-01-11T19:08:41.888-0600 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:61 Connection refused
```

You need to work with the packet filter to flush all the rules. See this article near the bottom in order to open port 27017 which is what mongod uses:

http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/how-open-specific-ports-in-os-x-1010-firewall-3616405/

This is quite direct:

https://gauravsohoni.wordpress.com/2015/04/14/mac-osx-open-port/

This may be less helpful but still worth glancing through:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201642